# Selection of a specific date in Calendar Date-picker using Selenium with Python

Tags: python

please I need some help with a piece of code. (I am a complete beginner so my code might be a mess, sorry for that)

I am trying to create an automated "date scheduler" to book a tennis court every Sunday of the week because I always seem to be too late and end up sitting around eating apples. -_-

The problem I am facing is selenium fills in all the required fields without a hitch, but when it comes to the calendar I just cannot figure it out. 
The date is in a tbody/tr/td element and xpath doesn't seem to identify it.

For reference I am using Python 3

```
    Problem: 

Date element is found in the following:
<td class="day">25</td>
```

Xpath does not identify this element accurately and I have no idea how to select the date as it is not labeled

I have tried everything from locating with class/id/name/text/xpath with no success and using Select(driver.find_element....) throws the error that Select cannot be used with div, tr, td.

Attempted to identify with driver.find_element_by_visible_text("") as suggested by online tutorials and this just does not work.

```
Current Code is as follows: 

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://gobook.co.za/')
time.sleep(2)

User = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='UserName']")
User.send_keys('XXXXXXXXX')
time.sleep(1)

Psw = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='Password']")
Psw.send_keys('XXXXXXXXX')
time.sleep(1)

Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
Button.click()
time.sleep(2)

Booking = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/Bookings/Client']")
Booking.click()
time.sleep(0.5)

New = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-toggle='collapse']")
New.click()
time.sleep(0.5)

Serv = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ServiceId']"))
Serv.select_by_value("6")
time.sleep(0.5)


Prov = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ProviderId']"))
Prov.select_by_value("22")
time.sleep(0.5)

Date = driver.find_element_by_id("BookingDate")
Date.click()
Date.send_keys('/25')
time.sleep(0.5)

Expected results = Select the date that falls on a Sunday (25th of August)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created an account and tested it. Would that be convienent for you?

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver72.exe')
driver.get('http://gobook.co.za/')
time.sleep(2)

User = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='UserName']")
User.send_keys('testgeo')
time.sleep(1)

Psw = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='Password']")
Psw.send_keys('testgeo')
time.sleep(1)

Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
Button.click()
time.sleep(2)

Booking = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/Bookings/Client']")
Booking.click()
time.sleep(0.5)

New = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-toggle='collapse']")
New.click()
time.sleep(0.5)

Serv = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ServiceId']"))
Serv.select_by_value("6")
time.sleep(0.5)


Prov = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ProviderId']"))
Prov.select_by_value("22")
time.sleep(0.5)

driver.find_element_by_id("BookingDate").clear()
Date = driver.find_element_by_id("BookingDate").send_keys('2019/08/25')
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kostas! :D That worked perfectly, the .clear() seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @WilcoScheepers Well if you send_keys to the datefield it will append the new data to existing and it would have 2019/08/222019/08/25 which is not allowed. So you first clear the input and then send the desired value! Glad that helped! :)